# "Cannot read property 'range' of undefined" when using async/await with Atom ESLint plugin

Tags: node.js, async-await, atom-editor, eslint

I am using Atom with the ESLint plugin. If it sees `async`/`await` keywords inside a file, it causes an error: "Cannot read property 'range' of undefined".

Is there a way to use `async`/`await` with ESLint in Atom, without getting this error?

Comment: [This answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43002676/4220785) makes me wonder if perhaps the ESLint plugin is out-of-date. Maybe it depends on `babel-eslint`. Have you updated your plugins?