# ESLint error in react-native after new module add(await/async)

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm getting this ESLint error from VisualStudio Code after adding this module [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) to my react native app and updating gradle to 4.4.1

> ESLint: Cannot read property 'range' of null. Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details.

[image]

Also the lint stoped woking properly.
I'm using the popular ESLint plugin for VSCode - ESLint
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Any suggestions?

PS the app with the new module works fine.

Comment: Seems the react-native-camera developers don't care much about static code analysis: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/316

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the error was cause because my version of `babel-eslit`, it doesn't support `await/async` and I used them to implement the  `react-native-camera` module.

More details about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978761/babel-eslint-typeerror-cannot-read-property-range-of-null).